# setscrollinfo npos within the last page

Tags: winapi, scrollbar

I have a problem (or misunderstanding) with the WinAPI SetScrollInfo

If I set it with the following scrollinfo struct

```
cbSize=28
fMask=4
nMin=0
nMax=30
nPage=12
nPos=20
nTrackPos=0
```

The result that comes back is 19 and not 20 ?

I'm trying to make a custom scroll bar for a grid

The nPage relates to the number of visible rows

Maybe I've misunderstood nPages's use and that is what is preventing me from setting nPos to anything other than <19

Ultimately it obviously needs to get to 30 in this case

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a symbolic constant for the `fMask` member. It allows readers to understand your code without digging through SDK headers, and helps other people find a solution.

Comment: The highest value that `nPos` can be is `nMax - nMin - nPage + 1`.

Comment: SIF_POS=4   @Jonathan Porter   So in my case 30 - 0 -12 +1 = 19  .... So I've missunderstood the use of nPage ? Thanks

Comment: To make it absolutely clear what should I be setting nPage to if it isn't the size of the 'page' of a grid etc and the amount you want it to jump in a PgDn ? Because in my example if it's anything other than 0 I cant set nPos all the way to 30 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting confused with. Let me try to figure out what your problem is visually if you scroll all the way to the bottom, do you see an extra pixel of scrollbar underneath the thumb?

Comment: It's not that. I'm trying to use a scrollbar to "control" a grid & page the data it shows from the database. Whilst the above example has tiny numbers to test a theory the real data set is much larger. I want the range of the scrollbar to represent the WHOLE dataset BUT the grid only ever contains one "page" of data to keep the performance acceptable and loads/dumps rows appropriately. So I need to be able to use nPos as a pointer for the full range of values I want to show. Sounds like my only option is to make nMax=real max+a page then I should be able to get/set npos between nMin and nMax?

Comment: `nPos` stores the position of the **first** visible line. At any time the visible range of lines is `[nPos .. nPos+nPage-1]`. If you set `nPos` to `nMax` then your first visible line is one line beyond the final line. The permissible ranges are documented at [SetScrollInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595.aspx).

Comment: With that information, you should know exactly what data to load. Another resource I suggest reading is Raymond Chen's scrollbar series; they're [the first articles (and then some) on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/default.aspx?PageIndex=445). (I'll need to make a list of them somewhere for future reference since they're not interlinked...) It discusses how to draw only the visible data range; the same logic can be applied to loading.